# Radical of an Ideal Proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ideals

> $\sqrt{\sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}} = \sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}$

$\sqrt{\sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}} \subseteq \sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}:$

Let $x \in \sqrt{\sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}}$, then $x^n \in \sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}$ for some $n > 0$.  Consider some $m > 0$ such that $x^{nm} = (x^n)^m \in \mathfrak{a}$.  Therefore, $x \in \sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}$ and $\sqrt{\sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}} \subseteq \sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}$.

$\sqrt{\mathfrak{a}} \subseteq \sqrt{\sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}}:$

Let $x \in \mathfrak{a}$.  Then $x^1 = x \in \mathfrak{a}$, thus $x \in \sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}$, i.e., $\mathfrak{a} \subseteq \sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}$.  So, consider $x \in \sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}$.  Then $\exists n>0$ such that $x^n \in \mathfrak{a} \subseteq \sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}$.  Thus $x^n \in \sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}$ for some $n>0$.  Therefore $x \in \sqrt{\sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}}$.  Hence $\sqrt{\mathfrak{a}} \subseteq \sqrt{\sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}}$.

> Is this proof correct?  Any help in correcting any stupid mistakes would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you for the help!!!

Comment: We always have $I\subseteq\sqrt I$, so the second part is somehow trivial.

Comment: @user26857 Is my proof correct minus me stating something obvious?

Comment: @user26857 Thank you!!